# how can i get an offline version of the iphone development handbook?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how can i get an offline version of the iphone development handbook?

Answer (score 2):

If you've already got XCode installed and running, from the menu bar go "XCode->Preferences" to open up the preferences window.  All the way to the right is a tab marked "Documentation".  In that window is a list of documentation, any thing you don't have locally will be grayed out, but will also have a "get" button next to it.  Hit that for any set of documentation you don't have installed and it will download itself.

Once that's done go to "Help->Developer Documentation" and you've got access to the doc's offline.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can only download it online because of the constant changes being made. Sorry bud.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the SDK/Xcode installed, the documentation set should live on your local drive. If you are looking for something like PDF or what ever, I have no help. There is an [atom feed](http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.atom) that is essentially a single post with an enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

That's true, all the documentation lives within XCode for that version of the SDK.